# Boolean cutting two objects is non-manifold

Tags: 3d-printing, boolean-modifier

I design a lot of hard surface 3D prints in Blender and use booleans on almost every model.  I need to know if there is a way to fix this:

If I use the same object to cut two overlapping objects then they become non-manifold when I export as an STL even if both are manifold separately.  The cutter obviously causes the vertices to be in the same location and the STL combines them causing a non-manifold issue. An example would be cutting a complex clip hole out of a design made up of layers of objects.

It also occurs if I use a slice to split an object in two so I can bevel the cut.

This happens on every model and normally I use two cutters and offset them slightly.  This seems to be a long winded workaround so is there a better option?